# Marshal Embedded Struct

Tags: go

I was playing around to learn how embedding works. http://play.golang.org/p/oHOim4G1-l

When I marshalled Child struct it marshals as `{}`. Why does it marshal like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON dictionary is empty because none of the fields of the struct (or any of the structures embedded inside the struct) are [exported](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

If you change the field names to start with an upper case letter, then the `encoding/json` module will be able to see them.  Of course since you've also got methods called `Name` and `Value`, you'll need to call them something else to avoid a conflict.