# Embedded JSON struct

Tags: json, mongodb, go

Here my struct

```
    type studentData struct {
        Name  string `bson:"name"`
        Grade int    `bson:"Grade"`
    }

    type student struct {
        student []studentData `json:"student"`
    }
```

I need my JSON result like this

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "Name": "ethan",
      "Grade": 2
    },
    {
      "Name": "rangga",
      "Grade": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the data from mongoDB, already tried to search but did not found that i need, could someone help me?

Comment: What's the problem you are having? How to you struct you JSON? Can you provide code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your JSON doesn't make a lot of sense, this will output the exact JSON you want:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
)

type Student struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Grade int    `json:"Grade"`
}

type Students struct {
    Array []Student `json:"array"`
}

func main() {

    student1 := Student{
        Name: "Josh",
        Grade: 2,
    }

    student2 := Student{
        Name: "Sarah",
        Grade: 4,
    }

    students := Students{
        Array: []Student{student1, student2},
    }

    b, err := json.Marshal(students)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    os.Stdout.Write(b)
}
```

Try the code here https://play.golang.org/p/PcPZOuxJUM

Answer (score 0):

For `encoding/json` to be able to marshal your struct, it needs to see the fields you want it to serialize.
In your case, `student.student` is not exported and therefore not visible to `encoding/json`. Export it and it works:

```
type student struct {
    Student []studentData `json:"student"`
}
```

A note on the side: Use something else than "Student" for a field of type `[]studentData` in a struct named "student". Maybe something like "Grades" or "TranscriptInformation"?

Another note on the side: Your desired JSON is not "right", identifiers/keys should not be capitalized, i.e. `"Name"` should be `"name"`.

Also, the search for `[go] embedded json` turned up questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599836/marshal-embedded-struct/31600100#31600100) ;)